# Add a string property to a DateTime property

Tags: c#, string, datetime, object

I'm building a C# object to add more strongly typed properties to a web app that accepts all of its parameters as strings. This web app displays all of a record's current values on the left, with blank fields on the right. If you leave a text input field blank, it leaves the corresponding value in the database unchanged. If you enter a new value, on submit it changes the corresponding value to the new value you entered.

In the app, date fields are entered in MM/dd/yyyy formatted strings. I have created DateTime equivilents in my C# object and use .ToString("MM/dd/yyyy") when sending them to the web app.

```
public DateTime NewHireDate
{
    get
    {
        return (DateTime.TryParse(NewValue11, out dateValue) ? dateValue : DateTime.MinValue);
    }
    set
    {
        NewValue11 = value.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
    }
}
```

One wrinkle is that the web app allows a user to enter "*BLANK" to essentially null out the value that's in the date field. I would like to extend that exact ability to my object by allowing the string "*BLANK" to be assigned as a value to my date property.

How would I redefine the NewHireDate property as a String so I could use myObject.NewHireDate = "*BLANK"?

Comment: It sounds like your property should be of type `DateTime?` instead of `DateTime` - at which point the property can be assigned the value `null`, which you could translate into `"*BLANK"` for the string property. You already *have* a string property - so that's what should use `"*BLANK"`.

Comment: The problem with that is that assigning null to the property would be equivalent to leaving the field blank, which in this scenario would be telling the web app not to change the value.

Comment: Okay, so it sounds like you need *two* sentinel values - `null` and something else (which could potentially be `DateTime.MinValue`), but you'd still just set the string property to `"*BLANK"`.

Comment: Note that you're currently prone to a subtle localization issue if the code is running on a machine where the date-separator is not `/` but for example `.`. Then `DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")` will result in `09.28.2016`. Use `value.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)`

Comment: I actually have a localized variable for the format string. I just used the literal to simplify my question.

Comment: Can you post a little more code, how are you inserting the data in db? I suppose that would be a right place to handle this condition.

Comment: Irrelevant. I'm not inserting data in the db. The web service is.

Answer (score 1):

As people said on the comments, u could use the type

> Datetime?

instead of Datetime.

This allows you to set an Datetime property the NULL value.

You can **complete this by creating methods on the class to convert** these strings into DateTime format.

Reference: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2cf62fcy(v=vs.140).aspx

Comment: Setting it to DateTime? wouldn't allow me to set the value = "*BLANK".

Comment: But you can convert the string "*Blank" into the null date ... and vice-versa.
IE: 

`'if(myString,equals("*Blank")){
     myDate = null;
}`'


and backwards... like
`
if(myDate == null){
myString = "*Blank";
`

And you can create this as a class method or extension...

Because you can't set an STRING into an Date... but you can make an interface that makes them to behave on a similar way..

Comment: But then I lose the advantage of having the strongly typed property.